# One exposed filter for multiple views

Tags: 7, views, uri

One exposed filter for multiple views

I have an exposed filter which is a date field containing a month and year using the “date module”.

I want to use different views to read the URL and filter with a “Contextual Filter”. This is how the URL looks and I can see it has separated out the Month and Year;

```
?field_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bmonth%5D=6&field_month_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Byear%5D=2016&=Apply.
```

I know the contextual filter in views is looking for 062016 so I’m struggling to read the URL in the contextual filter.
Is it possible to use PHP GET in the contextual filter to get the month and year and convert it to 062016?

```
if(isset($_GET[' field_month_value']))
    return $_GET[' field_month_value'];
else
    return;
```

I’m using D7. Thanks loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I believe you want one exposed filter to reload the page when chosen and then all the other views on the page follow that filter?

A workaround if no one else answers is to expose the filter on all views and hide the ones you don't want with css. In each view, go to the filter's settings under Admin at the bottom and you can rename them all to *field_month_value* if they're different.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, sounds like it is what I am looking for.